# Count Total Users and Clan using MySQLI in One query

Tags: php, mysql

i want return 2 value from my database,

this what i have done in 2 query :

```
$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1",$user_database,$password_database,$nama_database) or die(" User atau Password Database tidak Valid ");
$select_total_user=mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(`acct_username`) from `pvpgn_BNET`"));
$total_user=$select_total_user[0];
$select_total_clan=mysqli_fetch_array(mysqli_query($con, "SELECT count(`name`) from `pvpgn_clan`"));
$total_clan=$select_total_clan[0];
```

the value i want return is Total Users and Total Clans
in Single query
thanks

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. Are you saying the existing queries are working, and you just want to do the exact same thing in a single query?

Comment: ya, i want in single query

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In a single query it could be done like

```
select
( SELECT count(`acct_username`) from `pvpgn_BNET`) as total_user,
( SELECT count(`name`) from `pvpgn_clan` ) as total_clans ;
```

You can execute the query and fetch data by the index names `total_user` and `total_clans`

Answer (score 1):

```
select count(acct_username) AS c1, count(name) AS c2 FROM `pvpgn_BNET`, `pvpgn_clan`;
```